# Connecting to a postgresql instance running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, firewall, postgresql, windows-firewall

I have a VirtualBox VM running locally that has postgresql 9.6 installed on Windows 10. I am able to connect to the instance with pgadmin on the virtual machine. I am trying to connect to that same instance from the host machine.

I have created an inbound firewall rule:
[image]

My pg_hba.conf file contains the following:
`host all all 192.168.56.1/24 md5`

And my postgresql.conf file contains the following:
`listen_addresses = '*'`

I have restarted the service (and also Windows) after making those changes. From my host machine I get the following error when attempting to connect:
[image]

I have switched to Bridged Networking instead of the default NAT. I have also tried to disable the Windows Firewall completely on the VM and that did not help.

Network settings on the VM:
[image]

Any ideas on which settings I am missing?

Comment: What type of networking are you using?  Bridged or NAT?  You'd want to use bridged in this instance, otherwise you'll need to set up port forwarding in the VM's NAT settings.

Comment: I changed from NAT to Bridged and restarted the virtual machine, but still have the same message.

Comment: After you switched networking modes, did you adjust the firewall and IP?  You moved to the host's subnet when you changed from NAT, so the IP on the VM, firewall, etc need to be adjusted as well.

Comment: I did adjust the IP. What would have I needed to change on the firewall? I opened the port and the port should be the same after switching networking modes.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct IP?  A `192.168.x.1` address is typically the router in my experience.  That also looks like a host-only network address to me.  A bridged connection should get an IP on the same subnet as your host from your DHCP server.

Comment: What OS on the host? Does the Host-Only network adapter work better? A simple test is to disable firewalls on both host & guest to see if this is the problem.

Comment: @kicken I attached a new screenshot to the question with the network settings. Once I set to Bridged, I did an ipconfig on the VM and got a different address than I originally thought. However, I cannot ping the VM from the Host, and the VM does not have internet connectivity.

Comment: @harrymc I switched back to Host-Only and it works now. I suspect I had the incorrect IP address.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, I'm all set. If you post as an answer I'll award the bounty.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Host-Only network adapter is the best way to check for connection problems
between host and guest.

With the DHCP server that is built into VirtualBox, you don't need
anything else than setting the guest to that interface.
You could also temporarily disable the firewalls on both host and guest
if it still does not work.

For more information, see the VirtualBox Chapter 6 - Virtual networking, section
[Host-only networking](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly).